# Django: How to edit multiple rows in a model via forms

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a model, Book, that has a ForeignKey on the model Library. There can be multiple books in a library. Since the information about each book is brief, (author, age, cost), I want to list out all of the books in the library on one form and have the user be able to update all 3 fields at once. There is a `date` field and a `library_id` field that determine which books were added to the library on each day. We will assume that no new books can be added in the current form.

```
class Library(models.Model):
    user ...
    library_id = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True)
    updated    = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class Book(models.Model):
    library_id = models.ForeignKey(Library)
    date       = models.DateField(default=None, blank=True, null=True)
    author     = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    age        = models.IntegerField(default=0, min=0)
    cost       = models.DecimalField(default=0.00, max_digits=100, decimal_places=2)
    updated    = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('library_id ', 'date'),)
```

I want to be able to select a date for a specific library and to be able to update all of the information on all of the books at once. This means in the back end, I'll be updating multiple records in the `Book` class. I see that this exists: `inlineformset_factory`, but when I try to use it (see below) I still only get one form.

forms.py

```
class LibraryChangeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        exclude = ['updated']

BookFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Library, Book, exclude = ['updated'])
```

views.py

```
class LibraryUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model      = Library
    form_class = LibraryChangeForm
    def get_context_date(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(LibraryUpdateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form'] = LibraryChangeForm(self.request.POST, instance=self.object)
        context['book_form'] = BookFormSet(self.request.POST, instance=self.object)
        return context
```

html - only `{{form}}` and `{{form.as_p}}` work

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
    {{form}}
    {{book_form}}
    {{form.as_p}}
    {{form2}}
{% endblock %}
```

In short, I want to iterate of all of the instances for a specific library/date and have the user update all of them at once.

Answer (score 0):

First of all `LibraryChangeForm` should have model `Library` since it's using for update library instance

```
class LibraryChangeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Library
        exclude = ['updated']
```

Secondly to show formset in the view you can iterate over all formset's form:

```
<form method="post">
    {{form}}   
    {{ book_form.management_form }}
    <table>
        {% for book_form in book_form %}
        {{ book_form }}
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
</form>
```

This will render both: `LibraryChangeForm` and `BookFormset` on the same template.